# How to use popoverBackgroundViewClass in all lower version of iPad

Tags: ipad, ios5

I am using **popoverBackgroundViewClass** in my project. if make the build from iOS5 the build is working fine in iPad3 but it is crashing in iPad2. what can i do to execute the iOS5 build in all lower version of iPad

```
    if (version >= 5.0)
{

    pc.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [KSCustomPopoverBackgroundView class];

}
```

//pc------> UIPopOverCotroller   //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had a same problem i solved. when you are making build from iOS5 you should make sure

```
     iOS Deployment Target iOS 3.1
     ** Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C LLVM GCC 4.2**
```